# How can one select specific sibling of a context node using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How can one select a specific sibling of a context node using jQuery? Specifically, given context node `myContextNode` select the sibling `span` with class `myClass`.

```
document.evaluate("../span[@class='myClass']",
    myContextNode, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).
    singleNodeValue;
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) with a selector, like this:

```
$(myContextNode).siblings("span.myClass")
```